# Dirac delta function as a derivative of some function

Tags: dirac-delta, kronecker-delta

If $x=(x_1, x_2)$ is a two dimensional vector, then there is
$$\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} \log |x|^2 = 4\pi \delta(x)$$
where $\mu=1,2$ is summed over. This was given in, for example, chapter two of Polchinski's string theory book.

The question is: If $x=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ is a $n$ dimensional vector, is there a similar equation, which relates $\delta(x)$ to the derivative of some functions?

Comment: What's the difference between $\partial_\mu$ and $\partial^\mu$?

Comment: one answer is given by a "fundamental solution" to the Laplacian

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, I see.  It is the green's function.Thanks a lot! (There is no difference between $\partial^\mu$ and $\partial_\mu$ here. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not solution but the tip from where you can learn it (too cumbersome for a comment).

I suppose that you consider n-dimensional Euclidean space:

$\vec r=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n); \,r^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$

If

$$-\Delta_rg(\vec r,\vec r')=\delta^n(\vec r-\vec r')\quad \Rightarrow$$
$$g(\vec r,\vec r')=g(|\vec r-\vec r'|)=\frac{1}{(n-2)S_{n-1}}\biggl(\frac{1}{|\vec r-\vec r'|}\biggr)^{n-2}$$ Where $S_{n-1}= \frac{2\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$  - unit radius hypersphere surface area

The formula is nicely derived (using Schwinger's trick) for example, in "Mathematics for Physics" by Michael Stone
and Paul Goldbarts (section 6.5.4 Green function, pp 239 - 240).