# Bilaplacian equals Dirac distribution

Tags: functions, distribution-theory, laplacian

Define $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ when $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

Show that $\nabla^{(4)}f=\delta_0$ in the sense of distribution where $\nabla^{(4)}$ denotes the bilaplacian.

**My work**

Denoting $\phi(r)=r^2\ln(r)$ with $\phi(0)=0$, I have verified that its bilaplacian vanishes for $r\neq 0$ using the formula for polar coordinates, that is
$$\nabla^{(4)}\phi=\partial_r^4\phi+\frac2r\partial_r^3\phi-\frac1{r^2}\partial_r^2\phi+\frac1{r^3}\partial_r\phi$$
However, I can't seem to show that $\int_\mathbb{R^+}\nabla^{(4)}\phi(r)\varphi(r)\mathrm{d}r$ is equal to $\varphi(0)$. I have tried integrations by parts but it just gets out of hands and nothing comes off of it.

Comment: $\nabla^2\log r=-2\pi\delta^2(\vec r)$

Comment: Where does this come from ? And what is the meaning of $\delta^2$ ? Thanks !

Comment: $\delta^2(\vec r)$ denotes delta-function in 2-dimension space $\vec r=(x,y)$ The link to one of the sources is in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084314/dirac-delta-function-as-a-derivative-of-some-function/4084436#4084436

Comment: The option of $n=2$ is also considered in the book

Comment: With that I get to 
$$\nabla^4\phi=\Delta(\Delta\phi)=-4\pi\delta-2\pi\Delta(r^2\delta)$$
What to do from here ? In distribution $r^2\delta=0$ but then I am left with $-4\pi\delta$ which is not what I am supposed to have.

Comment: I'm afraid $2\pi$ will appear anyway... Maybe there is some specificity in $\delta_0$ in your notification ($2\pi$ is included)?

Comment: From your link, it seems that $\nabla^2\ln(r)=2\pi\delta_0$, there is no minus sign (see Green's function $G=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(r)$ satisfying $\Delta G=-\delta_0$. 

And I find $\nabla^4\phi=8\pi\delta_0$ with this. 

Indeed, it seems there is a prefactor missing. Thanks !