# Riesz potential integral equality.

Tags: integration, laplacian

I want to show

$$\Delta \frac{1}{n(n-1)\alpha(n)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}dy=f(x)$$

Where the $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of $n-$dimension unit ball.

I tried using the sphere coordination and failed. I think maybe it's relevant to Fourier transform somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac{const}{|x-y|^{n-2}}$ is a fundamental solution of Laplace equations in the space of $n$ dimensions: $\Delta_{x}\frac{const}{|x-y|^{n-2}}=\delta(x-y)$. FT can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084314/dirac-delta-function-as-a-derivative-of-some-function/4084436#4084436 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099027/computations-problem-with-reverse-fourier-transform/4099754#4099754

Comment: Are you sure that isn't supposed to be $n-2$ in the denominator?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, it's in the denominator.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea No, what I mean is, I think the $(n-1)$ you have there is actually supposed to be $(n-2)$.

Comment: No, I checked my question. You mean there is something wrong? I'm going to check the first comment and have another try. Let's discuss it later.

Comment: @K.defaoite I think you're right. When it's $n-2$, things are obvious. 
$$ LHS=\frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)} \int_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \nabla(\frac{1}{r^{n-2}})\nabla f(x+rs) r^{n-1} dr d\sigma(s)\\=
\frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)}\int_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} -(n-2) \nabla f(x+rs)\cdot s dr d\sigma(s)\\=-\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}f(x)d\sigma(s)=-f(x)$$